# Azure Onpremise Active Directory SSO

Tags: azure, active-directory

Trying to verify a custom domain for single sign in `Azure`.

We have an onpremise domain controller, its using a non-routable domain (contoso.prod).

Active directory in `Azure` and on-premise are syncing.

But if I add a custom routable domain contoso.com or contoso.net and check the box "I plan to configure this domain for single sign-on with my local `Active Directory`", the domains won't verify for single sign on. `Status = "Unverified"`

If I don't check that box, I'm able to verify the domain.

Is it because we have a non-routable domain on premise? Do we need to add a `UPN` suffix?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the box isn't necessary. You can either use AAD Connect to configure SSO, or you can install the Azure AD PowerShell module and run `Convert-MsolDomainToFederated` on your AD FS server.

Comment: gotcha. Do I still need to have Federation Services?

Comment: If you want SSO using your on-premises credential (so the password isn't sync'ed to AAD), then yes.